# Suppress Ruby warnings when running specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, warnings

I'm looking for a  way to suppress Ruby warnings when I run my specs.

```
spec spec/models/account_spec.rb
```

I receive warnings such as:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, ...
warning: already initialized constant SOME_CONSTANT_NAME
```

Removing the `ActiveSupport` warning is quite easy with `ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true`.

How do I prevent the already initialized constant warnings as part of my `spec` command? Or through creating another `spec` file that can suppress such warnings. Keep in mind that these warnings are from gem files, therefore I cannot go into those files and surround them with `Kernel.silence_warnings`.

**Note:**
I understand that suppressing warnings are bad. However, when I run a single `spec` from within `vim` it would be nice if the warnings didn't clutter my screen.

Comment: With Ruby 2.4, the `warning` gem is available to customize warning output: https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-warning

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you run your specs directly with the ruby command instead of the spec wrapper, you can use the -W command line option to silence warnings:

```
$ ruby --help
[...]
  -W[level]       set warning level; 0=silence, 1=medium, 2=verbose (default)
```

So in your case:

```
$ ruby -W0 -Ispec spec/models/event_spec.rb
```

should not show you any warnings.

Alternatively, you could set $VERBOSE=nil before your gems are loaded, ie at the top of your environment.rb (or application.rb if you're on Rails 3). Note that this disables all warnings all the time.

Or, since you are using Rails, you should be able to use Kernel.silence_warnings around the Bundler.require block if you're using Bundler:

```
Kernel.silence_warnings do
  Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
end
```

More selectively, set $VERBOSE only for loading specific gems:

```
config.gem 'wellbehaving_gem'
original_verbosity = $VERBOSE
$VERBOSE = nil
config.gem 'noisy_gem_a'
$VERBOSE = original_verbosity
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if `-W0` was set from within the Ruby file?

Comment: Yeah, just check the value of $VERBOSE. -W0 => nil, -W1 => false, -W2 => true

Comment: Thanks, Adding `$VERBOSE = nil` to my `Rakefile` silenced warnings for me.

Answer (score 94):

The syntax for `RUBYOPT` is

```
RUBYOPT="-W0" rspec
```

Tested in ruby 2.1.x and 2.14.x

Comment: and also works for minitest: `RUBYOPT=W0 rake test TEST=test/hi_test.rb`.

Comment: "export RUBYOPT=-W0 " worked for me as a general solution.

Answer (score 29):

Related with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240629/how-to-get-rid-of-email-regex-message-on-devise), you can manage deprecation warnings according to th environment in which you are working, as said in [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initializers):

> **active_support.deprecation_behavior** Sets up deprecation reporting for
>   environments, defaulting to **:log** for **development**, **:notify** for
>   **production** and **:stderr** for **test**. If a value isn't set for
>   config.active_support.deprecation then this initializer will prompt
>   the user to configure this line in the current environment's
>   **config/environments** file. Can be set to an array of values.

So just change in `config/environments/test.rb` the value **:stderr** for **:log**

```
Rails.application.configure do
   ...
   # Print deprecation notices to the log file instead of console.
   config.active_support.deprecation = :log
   ...
end
```

And with this change, the deprecation warnings will now be printed to the `log/test.log` instead of the console output.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me - passing -W0 did nothing.

Answer (score 20):

You can also use the "RUBYOPT" environment variable to pass -W0 to rspec:

```
RUBYOPT=W0 rspec spec/models/event_spec.rb
```

This allows you to run multiple specs by passing in a directory

```
RUBYOPT=W0 rspec spec/models
```

Comment: I had to use Dingle's answer for Ruby 2.2.2.

Answer (score 8):

The only solution that worked for me is to add `$VERBOSE = nil` on top of my config/environments/test.rb file

```rb
  Rails.application.configure do
   $VERBOSE = nil
```

I'm with faker warning problems `faker-1.9.6/lib/faker/default/number.rb:34`.
Use it local because it hides all other warnings.

Comment: This is only one solution that works in my macOS while `Warning[:deprecated] = false` works in my windows WSL.

Answer (score 8):

Putting `Warning[:deprecated] = false` after `require "rails/all"` in `config/application.rb` works very well to suppress those warnings everywhere. You can do

```rb
Warning[:deprecated] = false if Rails.env.test?
```

for your particular case, or better yet - put it in `config/environments/test.rb`, but I'm not sure how well it is going to work since I belive some stuff is loaded before that.

Answer (score 4):

If you have this in your `.rspec` file, remove

```
--warnings
```

from your `.rspec` file in your project root.

Comment: there is no `--warnings` there obviously

Answer (score 2):

---

rspec has a tag option you can use -- I simply used /dev/null.

```
rspec spec --deprecation-out /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using guard for tests and Rails 6 and you get warnings such as:
- "warning: **FILE** in eval may not return location in binding"
- "warning: Capturing the given block using Proc.new is deprecated; use `&block` instead"
- "warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call"

Then the only way so remove them all is to:

1. Add `$VERBOSE = nil` to `config/environments/test.rb`
2. Run guard with: `RUBYOPT='-W0' bundle exec guard`

I guess this is not good advice to remove all those warnings so later on, after a few gem updates, we should remove those lines again so that we get the right warnings on your own code usage for example.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, perhaps you shouldn't ignore your warnings, but test them, to make sure they are fired where they're supposed to be.

It's not the easiest to use, but it looks like this:

```
obj.should_receive(:warn).with("Some Message")
```

I [found it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449187/test-for-warnings-using-rspec), and tested it for my use case, and it works (and the warnings disappear from the console, of course)

Answer (score 0):

For individual specs:

```
around do |example|
  before = ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true
  example.run
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = before
end
```