# How to disable deprecation logging in rail 2.3.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rake

My App was developed in Rails 2.3.11 and Ruby 1.8.7p352.

When I try to run 'rake spec' lot of deprecation warning is displayed in console.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use   autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
config.load_paths is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths instead
config.load_paths= is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths= instead
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
```

How can I disable deprecation logging in rails 2.3.11?

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591509/suppress-ruby-warnings-when-running-specs

Comment: yeah, you can do that, or just find `load_paths` replace `autoload_paths` and you're done. Then a) your errors are gone, b) you're -1 deprecation from rails 3.

Comment: See answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126331/activesupportdeprecation-silenced-true-does-not-works-for-me

Comment: Hi can you mark the right answer or post the answer that worked for you, it might help others

Comment: @Ross  Marked answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126331/activesupportdeprecation-silenced-true-does-not-works-for-me

Answer (score 3):

In [Rails 2.3.9](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/9/4/ruby-on-rails-2-3-9-released/) config.load_paths and .load_once_paths has been renamed to config.autoload_paths and .autoload_once_paths. Some plugins (like Fckeditor) may still use the old version. Search for `load_paths` and replace it by `autoload_paths`, then the error should disappear.

Answer (score 2):

To turn off depreciation warnings, simply set

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true
```

You can also turn off warnings for specific code, with

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence do
  your_code_here 
end
```

Comment: This is not working in the mentioned Rails version.
If anybody looks for answer please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126331/activesupportdeprecation-silenced-true-does-not-works-for-me