# ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true does not works for me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, deprecated

My app was developed using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.11.

I am getting lot of deprecation warning while running 'rake spec'

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use   autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
config.load_paths is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths instead
config.load_paths= is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths= instead
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at /home/soundarapandian/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/desert-0.5.2/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, please use
```

I have tried adding

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true 
#in config/environments/test.rb
```

But still I am getting the warnings.How can I disable it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it will be `config.activesupport.deprecation = :silence` in the next major release. See https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5986.

Note that you could add

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation::DEFAULT_BEHAVIORS[:silence] = Proc.new { |message, callstack| }
```

to your app now as @carlosantoniodasilva mentions in the middle of the comments to get the `:silence` behaviour.

Popping the stack, though, the eat-your-broccoli answer would be to fix the deprecation warnings by changing over your `config.load_paths` calls in `config/application.rb` and elsewhere to `config.autoload_paths` as the warnings suggest. Mwah mwah advice about ignoring warnings over the long term, etc.