# How do I get rid of this mixture of errors when I run bin/rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundler, rspec-rails

I'm working on a Rails project and I am setting up RSpec with FactoryGirl, Faker, and DatabaseCleaner. This is my Gemfile so far:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'pg'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'lograge'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
end

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4', group: :doc
gem 'spring', group: :development
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

This is my `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Now, when I run the specs via the `bin/rspec` executable, I get this [mixture of warnings and errors](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rafalchmiel/02f39f03e09ed99211a9/raw/265d2f5be0fd0b32f605d22983be696ae71f3d65/gistfile1.txt) (I had to put it in a Gist because of the character limit on StackOverflow). Also, there seems to be some database warnings logged in my `log/test.log` file which is [also in a Gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rafalchmiel/9b3ce5325fccbddda972/raw/8606e7297ba09697453ce1d0283718b920b17e17/test.log).

If you look right at the end, the one spec I've written (which creates a new `Organisation` factory) actually passes. When `$VERBOSE = nil` the warnings and errors do not appear and all I get is:

```
.

Finished in 0.35145 seconds (files took 1.61 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

I can't seem to figure out what the warnings mean and I was wondering whether you know how to fix/get rid of them?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072876/too-many-warnings-about-circular-require-when-run-rspec?

Comment: @TimMoore It seems like it but the answer over there isn't a fix, just a way to keep the warnings quiet (just like I did with `$VERBOSE = nil`).

Comment: See: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1103

Comment: see Gushul's answer below...worked for me