# Guard warning "warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful"

Tags: ruby, rake, minitest, guard

I have a simple Ruby test envinvorment set up with:
minitest, guard, guard-minitest, and terminal-notifier-guard.

I'm using the following `Rakefile` so my tests are run by default because that's what Travis CI does by default.

```
require 'rake/testtask'
task :default => [:test]
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.pattern = "test/test_*"
end
```

The tests do run and pass but I get multiple screens worth of warnings. I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072876/too-many-warnings-about-circular-require-when-run-rspec) and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176446/rspec-capybara-loading-in-progress-circular-require-considered-harmful).

But it seems like those solutions are specific to rails and rspec.

Why am I getting these warnings?

You can find the full project on [GitHub](https://github.com/mbigras/some_working_ruby_minitest_guard_notifier_env) and the full error output in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/0dd0709042b6e435d9ded22d0de68a31)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to turn off the warnings, you can do so in the rake test task setup:

```
require 'rake/testtask'
task :default => [:test]
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.pattern = "test/test_*"
  t.warning = false
end
```

Comment: I believe the question was "Why am I getting these warnings?" this does not answer that.

Comment: @hoff2 the error says it all, there are circular requires. But since they are often in gems, turning it off is the only way to get rid of them.

Comment: downvoted for being a kludge.  warnings are useful. in this case this particular circular reference is not, but clobbering ALL warnings in your test suite is decidedly a bad idea.  you should want to see other warnings to address those issues

Comment: @jsharpe if you find another way to solve that, please feel free to add an answer

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo will do!