# How to get rid of email regex message on Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I'm using [Devise Token Auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gem and, everytime I run my test suite in Rails 4.2.5 app, I'm getting this deprecation warning from Devise:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: [Devise] config.email_regexp will have a new default on Devise 4.1
>   To keep the current behavior please set in your config/initializers/devise.rb the following:
>
> ```
> Devise.setup do |config|
>    config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\W]+\z/
> end
> ```
>
> If you want to use the new default:
>
> ```
> Devise.setup do |config|
>    config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
> end
> ```
>
> . (called from block in tsort_each at /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226)

I've already added *config/initializers/devise.rb* file manually and have set `email_regex` as suggested by the message above, but the annoying message persists.

How can I disable this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591509/suppress-ruby-warnings-when-running-specs), you can manage deprecation warnings according to th environment in which you are working, as said in [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initializers):

> **active_support.deprecation_behavior** Sets up deprecation reporting for
>   environments, defaulting to **:log** for **development**, **:notify** for
>   **production** and **:stderr** for **test**. If a value isn't set for
>   config.active_support.deprecation then this initializer will prompt
>   the user to configure this line in the current environment's
>   **config/environments** file. Can be set to an array of values.

So just change in `config/environments/test.rb` the value **:stderr** for **:log**

```
Rails.application.configure do
   ...
   # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
   config.active_support.deprecation = :log
   ...
end
```

And with this the depecation warning will be in the `log/test.log` instead in the console output