# Silence deprecation warning generated from of a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using the [unscoped_associations](https://github.com/markets/unscoped_associations) gem in my Rails 5.0.0.1 application.

I am getting this deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from <top (required)> at /home/rhl/myapp/config/application.rb:8)
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from <top (required)> at /home/rhl/myapp/config/application.rb:8)
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from <top (required)> at /home/rhl/myapp/config/application.rb:8)
```

How can I silence this warning in production environment?

I have tried adding:

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :silence
```

in `production.rb`

But it's not working.

Comment: This one worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591509/suppress-ruby-warnings-when-running-specs   (export RUBYOPT=-W0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true`

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore for a gem I'm using (numo-narray). Tried this line in a variety of places, with no success. Lukas's answer doesn't work either.

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 8):

Per the documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Deprecation/Behavior.html:

> Setting behaviors only affects deprecations that happen after boot time. Deprecation warnings raised by gems are not affected by this setting because they happen before Rails boots up.

I did find, however, that if you set it *before* your gems are required, it will silence warnings.

For example, place this line:

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.behavior = :silence
```

before

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

and it should silence the gem warnings.

Comment: I have tried your answer. Still I am getting the same deprecation warnings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41820913/3185510 worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: this won't work because gems are initialized before this point. This will have no effect on gems but will on rails specific warnings

Answer (score 2):

It's better to silence only the part you don't control or cannot easily fix:

```rb
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence do     
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn('something broke!')
end
# => nil
```

If it's inside the gem as in your case you can disable require in Gemfile and require that gem in initializers wrapped by silencer above.