# How can I figure out where a log message came from (and disable it)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am calling a redis command:

```
$redis.call ["MEMORY", "USAGE", "Job--9813"]
```

and when doing this I get a message logged:

```
Passing 'call' command to redis as is;
blind passthrough has been deprecated and will be removed in redis-namespace 2.0
(at (pry):37in '<main>')
```

I understand the warning but want to run the code anyway (for hundreds of thousands of keys) without spamming my terminal with these messages. How can i figure out where the message came from? I searched on the [`redis-rb`](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) repo, and couldn't find anything. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a `Kernel.warn` call in [`redis-namespace`](https://github.com/resque/redis-namespace/blob/e7da8a2bc63f27cccb4bda70bb580d470212d39d/lib/redis/namespace.rb#L352).

You can disable warnings in Ruby with the `-W0` command line option.

More info on disabling warnings here:
[Suppress Ruby warnings when running specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591509/suppress-ruby-warnings-when-running-specs)

Comment: Thanks. I just ended up doing it from runtime with `$VERBOSE = nil`

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons you may want to consider being rid of `redis-namespace` altogether.

First of all, Redis already has a built-in namespacing mechanism called "Databases".

You can read more about it here: http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/09/24/storing-data-with-redis/#data-partitioning

Comment: Fair enough but I am just investigating the existing Redis setup of the company I recently joined, not adding this gem myself :)