# Cocoapods hide ruby warnings

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

Is it possible to hide warnings that appear when I use the latest version of Cocoapods?

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:337: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
```

Some other warnings are also quite annoying:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:114: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/request.rb:61: warning: The called method `slug' is defined here
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:100: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/request.rb:61: warning: The called method `slug' is defined here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppress Ruby warnings when running specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591509/suppress-ruby-warnings-when-running-specs)

Comment: Put `RUBYOPT=W0` in your environment.

Comment: @anothermh no, doesn't work, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Same problems with ruby 2.7.1 and 2.7.2 but SOLVED for me with installing ruby 2.6.6:

1. install homebrew: `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. install rbenv (version manager): `brew install rbenv ruby-build`
3. prepare a terminal: `echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile source ~/.bash_profile`
4. install Ruby: `rbenv install 2.6.6`
5. activate the version: `rbenv global 2.6.6`
6. verify the activated version: `ruby -v`
   then reinstall cocoapods: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
   and in the app folder run:`pod install`